# trigger when check box is check automatically create child record

Tags: trigger, after-trigger

Create the field called "Contact Relationship" checkbox on the Contact Object and Create the related object called "Contact Relationship" which is related list to the Contacts.(Look Up Relationship).
Now logic is when we create contact by checking Contact Relationship checkbox, then Contact Relationship will be created automatically for that contact.

```
trigger updatecustomerrelationship on Contact (after insert,after update) {
    list<contact> conlist = new list<contact>();
    list<Contact_Relationship__c> conrelationship = new list<Contact_Relationship__c>();

    for(contact con:trigger.new) {
        if(con.Prequalified__c == true){
            Contact_Relationship__c conrelat = new Contact_Relationship__c();
            conrelat.name = con.Lastname;
            conrelat.Contact__c = con.id;
            conrelationship.add(conrelat);
        }

        insert conrelationship;
    }
}
```

The thrown error is:

> Variable does not exist: Contact__c

Comment: This really can only mean the 1 thing (since it only appears once in your code) and that is that your custom object does not have a field named "contact__c" on it.

Comment: Make sure your insert is outside of the for-loop, otherwise, you'll get some errors when "bulkifying" it.
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code

Answer (score 0):

A few considerations:

- List variable conlist is not being used
- The insert should be outside of the for-loop;
- Name (Contact Relationship) might not be changed, it depends on how you've configured that. It might receive a name automatically (that's why I'm not considering it);
- The Contact__c should not be a problem, just make sure that there is a lookup to the Contact object and double check the API name on your Contact Relationship object.

Find below the same trigger with some changes...
I hope it helps...

```
trigger updateCustomerRelationship on Contact (after insert,after update) {
    List<Contact_Relationship__c> contactRelationships = new List<Contact_Relationship__c>();

    for(Contact con : trigger.new) {
        if(con.Prequalified__c == true){
            Contact_Relationship__c contactRelationship = new Contact_Relationship__c();
            //contactRelationship.Name = con.LastName; 
            contactRelationship.Contact__c = con.id;
            contactRelationships.add(contactRelationship);
        }
    }
    insert contactRelationships;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I miss the relationship create on Contact_Relationship__c to contact that lookup relationship. 
Relationship Field API ContactRela__c map of ID so that why they showing error. Thank you so much to respond.

trigger is working properly issue clear

```
trigger updateCustomerRelationship on Contact (after insert,after update) {
    List<Contact_Relationship__c> contactRelationships = new List<Contact_Relationship__c>();

    for(Contact con : trigger.new) {
        if(con.Prequalified__c == true){
            Contact_Relationship__c contactRelationship = new Contact_Relationship__c();
            contactRelationship.Name = con.LastName; 
            contactRelationship.ContactRela__c = con.id;
            contactRelationships.add(contactRelationship);
        }
    }
    insert contactRelationships;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pablo - you can make your code more concise by using the nifty [Bluewolf Selector GitHub package](https://github.com/bluewolf-beyond/selector) - which has way more features that are worth exploiting elsewhere in your codebase.

```
...
for (Contact con : Select.Field.isEqual( Contact.Prequalified__c,true )
                   .filter( Trigger.new) {
    contactRelationships.add(new Contact_Relationship__c(
                  Contact__c = con.Id,
                  Name = con.LastName));
}
insert contactRelationships;
```

Answer (score 0):

So two things I would make note of is that in your original post, you're handling this anytime the record is marked TRUE in the Prequalified__c Field.
The issue that I see with this is that any update to this record will trigger creation of a record. NOT only when we change this field from false to true.

So, with that in mind I would use the below code to evaluate for a change and to then and only then make this record.

Also I saw that you were inserting within a loop - that is a bad idea as well so I moved your list insert to the end of your trigger execution. 
I would however suggest, to address your error, like others here have also pointed out, verify that your Parent field is named properly in the method where you're setting it here.

```
    trigger updateCustomerRelationship on Contact ( after insert, after update ){

        List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact>();
        List<Contact_Relationship__c> conRelationships = new List<Contact_Relationship__c>();

        Map<Id, Contact> oldRecords = Trigger.isUpdate ? Trigger.oldMap : null;

        for( Contact c : Trigger.New ){

            Contact oldContact = oldRecords != null ? oldRecords.get( c.Id ) : null;

            Contact_Relationship__c rel;
            // on insert if we have this checked = lets fo this
            if( Trigger.isInsert && c.Prequalified__c ){
                rel = new Contact_Relationship__c( 
                    Contact__c = c.Id,
                    Name = c.LastName
                );

            }
            // if we are updating and we have triggered this to create ( we don't want to create one on every contact update - only when we want to create this, yeah? )
            else if( Trigger.isUpdate && oldContact != null && ( oldContact.Prequalified__c != c.Prequalified__c && c.Prequalified__c )){
                rel = new Contact_Relationship__c( 
                    Contact__c = c.Id,
                    Name = c.LastName               
                );

            }

            if( rel != null ){
                conRelationships.add( rel );
            }
        }

        // insert relationships if any were created 
        if( !conRelationships.isEmpty() ){

            try{
                Database.insert( conRelationships );
            }
            catch( Exception ex ){
                System.debug( 'Error inserting contact relationships: ' + ex.getMessage() );
                ... Do some error handling here 
            }
        }
    }
```